# How do I create every combination of single elements selected from multiple arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, combinatorics

I have 5 arrays:

```
["A", "B", "C"]
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
["A"]
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"]
```

I would like to create a list of each combination as such:

```
["AAAAA","AAAAB","AAAAC", "AAAAD"...
 "BAAAA","BAAAB","BAAAC", "BAAAD"...]
```

Comment: so... you need every combination of elements?

Comment: What did you try and what were the specific problems you had?

Comment: how you get the second array...under which logic?

Comment: @YoursTruly, obvious solution is: N nested loops (N = 5 in your case)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
a = [
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
  ["A"],
  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"]
]

a.inject(&:product).map(&:join)
# => ["AAAAA", "AAAAB", "AAAAC", ..., "CEAFM", "CEAFN", "CEAFO"]
```

---

Thanks to bluexuemei for the improved answer. The original solution was `a.shift.product(*a).map(&:join)`.

---

#### A More Traditional Solution

With such a convenient library, these ruby one-liners seem almost like cheating.

Here is a more traditional way to solve this common problem that can be readily coded into other programming languages:

```
N = a.reduce(1) { |product,list| product * list.size } # 1350

combinations = []
0.upto(N-1) do |q|
  combo = []
  a.reverse.each do |list|
    q, r = q.divmod list.size
    combo << list[r]
  end
  combinations.push combo.reverse.join
end
combinations
# => ["AAAAA", "AAAAB", "AAAAC", ..., "CEAFM", "CEAFN", "CEAFO"]
```

The basic idea is to first calculate the total number of combinations `N` which is just the product of the length of all the lists. Each integer from `0` to `N-1` then encodes all the information needed to provide unique indices into each list to produce each combination. One way to think of it is that the index variable `q` can be expressed as a 5-digit number, where each digit is in a different base, where the base is the size of the corresponding list. That is, the first digit is base-3, the second digit is base-5, the 3rd is base-1 (always 0), the 4th is base-6, and the 5th is base-15. To extract these values from `q`, this is just taking a series of repeated integer divisions and remainders, as done in the inner loop. Naturally this requires some homework, perhaps looking at simpler examples, to fully digest.

Comment: What is the *a doing here?: a.shift.product(*a).map(&:join)

Comment: @YoursTruly `a.shift` removes and returns the first array, then calls [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product) on the remaining 4 arrays. In order to pass the remaining 4 arrays as 4 separates parameters rather than a single array, that is what the * does. It is known as the "splat" operator, since it splats out the array into parameters without the surrounding []s.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.reduce(&:product).map(&:join).size
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer, better than the `shift`/splat method.